# Border disappears with Sticky Header

Tags: css, sticky

I tried looking for a solution to this problem here but it seems that the closest solution I "MAY" have is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708146/first-row-of-table-disappears-once-the-column-headers-are-fixed-sticky-header). However this is for tables. Since I am still quite new to this, I'm not sure how to apply this solution to my problem. Or if this is even the right solution for this.

My issue is that the border(bottom) of my blog post titles disappear when the nav bar sticks. The particular border-bottom I'm referring to is the dashed line under the blog-post date, share, and like button. I would've liked to add a screenshot but since I'm new here, SO won't let me yet.

This issue only happens on iPad *I believe*. So I'm not sure if my iPad (1st gen) is the problem or not. My blog is bizinformant.tumblr.com

Many thanks!

Here's the following html css jQuery:

```
/*blog post box*/
#content #posts {
    width:800px;
    margin:20px auto 50px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#f7f3ef;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding:10px 20px 24px;
    }

/*this border-bottom of this element disappears when nav bar sticks*/
#permy {
    font-style:normal;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:1.3em;
    text-align:left;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    border-bottom:1px dashed #000;
}

#mainnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    width:100%;
    z-index:3;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
    }

#mainnav ul {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    z-index:3;
}
#mainnav li {
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px;
    z-index:3;
}

/*stickydiv*/
#stickyalias {
    display: none;
    height: 10px;
}

$(function(){
    // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#mainnav').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                    $('#mainnav').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', left: '0px'});
                    $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
            } else {
                    $('#mainnav').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                    $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'none');
            }
    });
});

{block:Text}
        {block:Title}
            <h1 class="title">
                <a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a>
            </h1>
                <div id="permy">
                    <a href="{Permalink}" class="date">
                        {block:Date}{ShortMonth} {DayOfMonth}, {ShortYear} {/block:Date}
                    </a>

                    {block:NoteCount}
                    <span id="dashy">-</span>
                    <a href="{Permalink}#notes" class="notes">
                        <span class="perm">{NoteCountWithLabel}
                    </a>
                    {/block:NoteCount}
                    <div class="my-like" title="Like">{LikeButton color="black"}</div>

                    {block:HasTags}
                    <a href="{ReblogURL}" class="reb">
                        <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/tnbktxc/HWun9rla7/reblog.png" class="reblogbutton">
                    </a>
                    {/block:HasTags}
                </div>
        {/block:Title}
            <div class="text">{Body}</div>
        {block:More}
            <div class='rmlink'>
                <a href="{Permalink}">Read more</a>
             </div>
        {/block:More}
{/block:Text}<!--textpost-->
```

Comment: tried it on different browsers and iPad Air and works without problems

Comment: Thanks Fabio. So I guess it must that my iPad is old (1st gen).

Comment: I thought there's an error on my part that's doing this to iPads. Tnx again.